# PowerBI Desktop - Hide Filter Panel and Take Full Page Width

Tags: angular, powerbi, report, embed

We are trying to embed a PowerBI on-prem report in our Angular application.
We used the powerbi-client-angular to do this (We had to add this query string `?rs:embed=true` to make it work).

There are settings provided in this package that allows to hide/show the filter panel, as well as to let the report take the full page width. However, this doesn't seem to work.

Can you suggest other ways we can achieve these?

- Hide filter panel
- Take full page width

I've tried embedding a report coming from PowerBI Service and this worked. However, it still doesn't take the full width of the page

Comment: Try adding `&$filterPaneEnabled=false`